# Unable to Alter table as a Database-Owner

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to `alter` a `primary key` of a table to **auto-increment**. I try to make the changes both with SQL code and manually, but it looks like I am not given the permission, even tho I am the `database owner`. I have disconnected every relationship with the table but I am not still allowed. The property option is greyed out. Thanks in advance.

Am using the SQL code below:

```
ALTER TABLE product DROP COLUMN prod_id 
ALTER TABLE product ADD prod_id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

But I got this error message:

> "Msg 4902, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot find the object "product"
>   because it does not exist or you do not have permissions."

Note: (the table is available and works with "select statement")

Comment: Are you using **mySQL** or **SQLServer**? Please only use tags relevant to your actual question.

Comment: are you sure you are connected to the correct db?

Comment: Am using SQLSERVER @fvu

Comment: It works now. I closed and restarted the SQL server and everything works fine now. Thank you for your help.